# Scala pattern match and logical not

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have:

```
 x match { 
  case a: SomeType => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomethingElse()
 }
```

Is there a way to check that 'a' is NOT of a given type?

like so:

```
x match { 
  case !(a: SomeType) => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

**Edit:** I agree the question may not be very clear but my interest was mostly the logical not and it has been answered.

Comment: !(a: MyFirst) will include MySecond and will include the other case. is this what you need? like the pattern matching now doesn't have a meaning.

Comment: i agree, my question was really more about the logical not

Comment: They didn't allow it because it doesn't make sense. as I mentioned in my answer. checking the not is the same as checking the case you need and any other case.

Comment: If you need this answer use if statement, not pattern matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
x match { 
  case a: if !a.isInstanceOf[MyFirst] => doSomething()
  case b: MySecond => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question as well as something I wish to never see in my code.

Comment: it's not logically correct as `!a.isInstanceOf[MyFirst]` will include `MySecond` and will include any other case but `MyFirst`

Comment: "Is there a way to check that 'a' is NOT of a given type?"

Comment: This could be an if statement not in pattern matching.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I'm very close to create one more account to upvote your comment once more.

Comment: What's bad about it ?

Comment: @jakstack Functional Scala devs dont like to use those things

Answer (score 4):

After your edit. What you need is the same as:

```
x match { 
  case a: SomeType => doSomethingElse()
  case _ => doSomething()
}
```